# WSO2 identity server NullPointerException on OAuth2 login when account is locked

Tags: locking, oauth-2.0, account, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2is 4.6.0 and i'm testing the "Account lock/unlock" functionality.

Here is the configuration i use from the *identity-mgt.properties* file :

```
# If account verification is not enabled, following property will decide where user must be lock or not after user is created 
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Creation=true
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.Time=5
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure=true
Authentication.Policy.Account.Lock.On.Failure.Max.Attempts=3
```

On three login failure, the account is locked for 5 minutes

The account is locked and unlocked as expected, it works perfectly, but while the account is locked, when i try to login using OAuth2 (code flow) i get the following error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:331)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:159)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:206)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:242)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:223)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:174)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:162)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:128)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:194)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:100)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:57)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:93)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.amber.oauth2.common.message.OAuthResponse$OAuthErrorResponseBuilder.error(OAuthResponse.java:165)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:172)
at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorizePost(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:288)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
... 58 more
```

Did i missed something in the configuration ?
Any advice to avoid this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying get an access token while your account is lock?  Basically you can not get an access token when you are locked as you are not an authenticated user. But i agree that there can not be a null pointer. You must return with an authentication failure message. This must be a bug in the code.. If you just look for the source of "OAuth2AuthzEndpoint", you can see that there is a possible null pointer.  When user is not authenticated, It tries to create an OAuth error message but it fails to create the OAuth error message due this null pointer..  I hope this would fix in next release.